# Add manually a resource to the browser cache

Tags: javascript, ajax, browser-cache

I need to retrieve many icons from my server using ajax.
The icons are usually retrieved one by one.

However, to reduce the server load, I've thought of retrieving all the icons one time and then cache them in the browser one by one.

Is it possible? 
The problem is with caching the icons in the browser one by one.

Before: (3 requests)

```
'/static/icon1' -> cached '/static/icon1'
'/static/icon2' -> cached '/static/icon2'
'/static/icon3' -> cached '/static/icon3'
```

After: (1 request)

```
'/static/all_icons' -> cached '/static/icon1', '/static/icon2', '/static/icon3'
```

Comment: you could use icon sprites, or a zip file of icons.

Comment: The problem is about how to cache them singularly, not about how to download them

Comment: not sure what you mean; downloading them _is_ how you populate the cache. how are you downloading more than one url at once?

Comment: https://flaviocopes.com/cache-api/

Comment: IVO GELOV, yes I've read that experimental feature before posting the question. It seems that is the only way at the moment.